# Delete and Update Graphql mutation in Amplify ReactJs

Tags: graphql, aws-amplify, graphql-mutation

Amplify automatically generates mutations for delete like this:

```
export const deleteTodo = /* GraphQL */ `
 mutation DeleteTodo($input: DeleteTodoInput!) {
  deleteTodo(input: $input) {
   index
   body
   hasRead
 }
```

and this is how I call it in my App.js

```
await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(mutations.deleteTodo, {input: result}));
```

It returns an error like this. Seems like the data has not been passed

```
message: "The variables input contains a field name 'index' that is not defined for input object type 'DeleteTodoInput' "
```

Comment: `DeleteTodoInput` description and actual (before call API) `result` ?

Comment: can you clearly explain this please, I'm pretty new to this

Comment: show this type definition - even generated is defined somewhere - you must know what it contains .... https://www.howtographql.com/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what `result` is but you can try:

```
const result = {
  index: 1,
  body: 'blabla',
  hasRead: true,
}

await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(mutations.deleteTodo, {input: { ...result }}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with the result variable. It should be {result} and it should have the index. Incase you dont have index remove it from the query

```
const deleteTodo = /* GraphQL */ `
 mutation DeleteTodo($input: DeleteTodoInput!) {
  deleteTodo(input: $input) {
   body
   hasRead
 }

await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(mutations.deleteTodo, {input: {result}));
```